# multi select is not being displayed through ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm implementing multi select through bootstrap. When i wrote it directly on page it works fine. I call ajax on select of drop down that is already existed in my page.
[here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) is the tutorial for multi select which i'm following.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" /> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
    $('#c_company').change(function() {
        c_company = $('#c_company').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'get_company_data.php',
            data: {
                'c_company' : $('#c_company').val()
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
                //alert(result);
                $(".col-lg-8").html(result);

            }
        });    
    });    
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id='c_company' name='company'>
<option value='Bunnny'>Bunny</option>
<option value='Nestle'>Nestle</option>
<option value='Coke cola'>Coke cola</option>
<select>
<div class='col-lg-8'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is get_company_data.php file code.

```
<?php

echo "<select class='selectpicker' multiple >
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>";

?>
```

ajax call is working fine and it returns right data because i'd shown it by putting response on alert function. I don't know where i'm doing wrong because if html is directly visible on page then it must get visible by ajax call too. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Show us what you receiving in `result`

Comment: Where did you add `jQuery` ?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: add multiple at the end of this line <select id='c_company' name='company'>  , so this line should read <select id='c_company' name='company' multiple>

Comment: i'm going to add the response too.

Comment: @Satya multilpe select tag is coming from ajax response

Comment: If alert shows the result ok, then try giving this div a particular id and then use that to populate the div. It is a long shot...

Comment: @T.Shah i'm showing it by using class right now.. i've tried through id too.. no luck :(

Comment: Is it because of col-lg-8.... Are you viewing it on smaller screens? try to remove the class and then use it with id...

Comment: @T.Shah i tried it with id too.. its not working

Comment: remove the class... use only id. Make it like - <div id='your id here'>

Comment: i did the same bro :)